# Converting a Gregorian date to Julian Day Count in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdate, gregorian-calendar, julian-date

I need Objective C method for converting Gregorian date to Julian days same as this PHP method (GregorianToJD).

Comment: Use a NSDateFormatter with a dateFormat of "g".

Comment: @HotLicks: You are right! I had never noticed the "g" format.

Comment: @MartinR - Whenever you want to do anything weird with dates you should always scan through the [date format standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: @HotLicks: Thanks for reminding me :-) (But this way I learned something about the Julian day.)

Comment: The "g" specifier is not exactly a Julian day. From the [docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), "Modified Julian day. This is different from the conventional Julian day number in two regards. First, it demarcates days at local zone midnight, rather than noon GMT. Second, it is a local number; that is, it depends on the local time zone. It can be thought of as a single number that encompasses all the date-related fields."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day, the Julian day number for January 1, 2000, was 2,451,545. So you can compute the number of days between your date and this
reference date. For example (Jan 1, 2014):

```
NSUInteger julianDayFor01012000 = 2451545;
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.year = 2014;
comp.month = 1;
comp.day = 1;
NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
comp.year = 2000;
comp.month = 1;
comp.day = 1;
NSDate *ref = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

NSDateComponents *diff = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:ref toDate:date options:0];
NSInteger julianDays = diff.day + julianDayFor01012000;
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)julianDays);
// Output: 2456659
```

This gives the same result as http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php:

```
<?php
$jd = GregorianToJD(1, 1, 2014);
echo "$jd\n";
?>
```

Inverse direction (Julian days to Gregorian year/month/day):

```
NSInteger julianDays = 2456659; // From above example
NSUInteger julianDayFor01012000 = 2451545;
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.year = 2000;
comp.month = 1;
comp.day = 1;
NSDate *ref = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
NSDateComponents *diff = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
diff.day = julianDays - julianDayFor01012000;

NSDate *date = [cal dateByAddingComponents:diff toDate:ref options:0];
comp = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%04ld-%02ld-%02ld", (long)comp.year, (long)comp.month, (long)comp.day);
// Output: 2014-01-01
```

**UPDATE:** As Hot Licks correctly stated in a comment, it is easier to use a date
formatter with the "g" format:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.year = 2014;
comp.month = 1;
comp.day = 1;
NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"g"];
NSInteger julianDays = [[fmt stringFromDate:date] integerValue];
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)julianDays);
// Output: 2456659
```

And for the inverse direction:

```
NSInteger julianDays = 2456659;
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"g"];
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:[@(julianDays) stringValue]];
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%04ld-%02ld-%02ld", (long)comp.year, (long)comp.month, (long)comp.day);
// Output: 2014-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks , also i need the inverse like this method ( JDToGregorian)

Comment: There is an ambiguity in this answer and this solution should be used with caution. @nerdist colony's answer is better. Why? Because the Julian date value given at the start of this post (2,451,545) is the value for Jan 1 2000 at 12:00 GMT (noon). Times BEFORE 12:00 on that date range from 2,451,544.5 - 2,451,545.0 and times AFTER 12:00 on that date range from 2,451,545.0 to 2,451,545.5. One can depend on rounding to help but be clear about what you are doing.

Comment: The "g" specifier is not exactly a Julian day. From the [docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), "Modified Julian day. This is different from the conventional Julian day number in two regards. First, it demarcates days at local zone midnight, rather than noon GMT. Second, it is a local number; that is, it depends on the local time zone. It can be thought of as a single number that encompasses all the date-related fields."

Comment: @wod: It seems that the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709317/1187415 is better (and simpler), you might consider to accept that one instead of mine.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for the feedback. I have suggested to OP to accept the other answer instead (which is simpler *and correct* if I understand it correctly). I will then delete this one.

Answer (score 13):

### **Precision: Incorporating *time of day* in Julian Date conversions**

These Julian date conversion methods yield results identical to the  **[U.S. Naval Observatory](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/JulianDate)** Online Julian Date Converter, which is more precise than `NSDateFormatter's` Julian Date conversion. Specifically, the functions below incorporate time-of-day (e.g. hour, minute and seconds), whereas `NSDateFormatter` rounds to noon GMT.

**Swift examples:**

```
func jdFromDate(date : NSDate) -> Double {
    let JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT = 2440587.5
    return JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT + date.timeIntervalSince1970 / 86400
}

func dateFromJd(jd : Double) -> NSDate {
    let JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT = 2440587.5
    return  NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (jd - JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT) * 86400)
}
```

**Objective-C examples:**

```
double jdFromDate(NSDate *date) {
   double JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT = 2440587.5;
   return JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT + date.timeIntervalSince1970 / 86400;
}

NSDate dataFromJd(double jd) {
   double JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT = 2440587.5;
   return [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970: (jd - JD_JAN_1_1970_0000GMT) * 86400)];        
}
```

***Note***: *Research confirms that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22830318/2079103) rounds the date to a 24-hour interval because it uses the `g` format-specifier of `NSDateFormatter`, which returns the [Modified Julian Day](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/ModifiedJulianDate.html), according to the UNICODE standard's [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) that Apple's date formatting APIs adhere to (according to the [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)).*

Comment: In your Objective-C example, that should be `NSDate *date`, not `NSDate date`

Comment: I did not do that because last time I tried a change of just one character, I got an edit that said I had to change more than that, an absurd edit, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = Date() // now
let cal = Calendar.current
var day = 0
day = cal.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: date) ?? 0
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.